# How to close file_object in Python

Tags: python

I don't want to use the `with` operator right now. How can I achieve this using try-catch?

```
try: 
  file_object = open('todo.txt')
except FileNotFoundError: 
  print("The file is not found")
finally: 
  file_object.close() # file_object is not defined
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**

```
file_object = None 

try: 
  file_object = open('todo.txt')
except FileNotFoundError: 
  print("The file is not found")
finally: 
  if file_object is not None: 
    file_object.close()
```

Comment: Define `file_object` outside `try` and set it to `None`. In `finally`, check if it's `None`, and if it isn't, close it.

Comment: But seriously, use `with`. Less chances for bugs.

Comment: Or simply `if not file_object`

Comment: I’ll second what @FedericoklezCulloca said. Use [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), always. What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `else` instead of `finally`. `else` triggers only if the code in the try block ran without any errors.

```
try: 
  file_object = open('todo.txt')
except FileNotFoundError: 
  print("The file is not found")
else:
  file_object.close()
```